# Pass a PHP array to Google Maps API JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to create a way to loop through a bunch of address and output a list of ones that are within a set distance from another address. So In WordPress, I have a custom post type I am looping through and creating an array of addresses like this,

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'friday_location', 'posts_per_page' => '-1' );
$arr = array();
$i=0;
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

$meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID);

$string = $meta['_cmb_address'][0] . '+' . $meta['_cmb_city'][0] . '+' .$meta['_cmb_state'][0] . '+' .$meta['_cmb_zip'][0];
$string = str_replace(' ', '+', $string);

$arr[$i] = $string;
$i++;

endwhile; 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

After this, inside of the script tag I am converting the array like this

```
var locations = <?php echo json_encode($arr ); ?>;
```

Now I have a JS array, I think, of addresses and I am wanting to pass this array into the Google Maps API Distance Matrix, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#distance_matrix_requests

The relevant code piece looks like,

```
function calculateDistances() {
    var opts = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.6,-98),
    zoom: 4,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), opts);
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    service.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
    origins: [origin2],
    destinations: locations,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
    }, callback);
}
```

I know the destinations can take an array, so I am trying to give it one, dynamically made, however I am not sure why it is not working as I see it in my head :)

Comment: Can you upload it to a demo server? Are you getting any JS parsing errors?

Comment: You don't actually have an array, you have a string with JSON format, and you don't even have that in javascript, as you forgot the quotes for the string ?

Comment: It is all local right now... JS error says                      Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined localhost:136
callback localhost:136
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
uE.(anonymous function).b.c
uE.(anonymous function).b
(anonymous function)
q
(anonymous function) DistanceMatrixService.GetDistanceMatrix:1

Comment: Yikes, sorry, not very helpful posting that error message in here, kinda crunched.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
var locations = <?php echo json_encode($arr ); ?>;
```

should probably be:

```
var locations = '<?php echo json_encode($arr ); ?>';
```

But that's just a string, to get an array do:

```
var locations = '<?php echo json_encode($arr ); ?>',
         JSON = JSON.parse(locations),
    loc_array = [];

for(var key in JSON) {
    if(JSON.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        loc_array.push(JSON[key]);
    }
}
```

now pass that array to the Google function:

```
service.getDistanceMatrix( 
{
   origins: loc_array,
......
```

Comment: Thanks, I gave that a shot and now get this JS error,          Uncaught TypeError: Object address+one+here,address+two+here has no method 'stringify'